# How to replace date column with NAs with an if condition

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I am struggling to find an easier/simpler way to replace a date column in a dataset (tibble) with NA under specific conditions.

Here is a code that actually attemps to do the task. What I want is to replace dates more recent than June 2020 and older than Jan 1900 with missing values, without changing missing values that are already there. But this code is very ugly. Is there a simpler way to do it, specially using tidyverse tools?

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

x <- seq(1,5)
y <- c(dmy("04/02/1863", "29/10/1989", "16/03/2000", "14/05/2021", NA))
dat <- tibble(x,y)

dat$y[which(dat$y >= dmy("01/06/2020") | dat$y < dmy("01/01/1900"))] <- 
  rep(NA, length(dat$y[which(dat$y >= dmy("01/06/2020") | dat$y < dmy("01/01/1900"))]))

dat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `if_else` like so:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

x <- seq(1,5)
y <- c(dmy("04/02/1863", "29/10/1989", "16/03/2000", "14/05/2021", NA))
dat <- tibble(x,y)

dat %>% 
  mutate(y = if_else(y >= dmy("01/06/2020") | y < dmy("01/01/1900"), NA_Date_, y))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x y         
#>   <int> <date>    
#> 1     1 NA        
#> 2     2 1989-10-29
#> 3     3 2000-03-16
#> 4     4 NA        
#> 5     5 NA
```

Comment: Thank you stefan, it works just fine. I have tried similar stuff but it did not work, but I also did not know the existence of "NA_Date_". I just ran in a database with 1.5 million observations and it ran really fast.

Comment: You are welcome. Always glad to help. BTW: Did not know about "NA_Date_" either. But I knew about "NA_character" and "NA_integer_" ... so I gave it a try. (; Best S.

Answer (score 2):

The same answer with @stefan with `case_when` syntax if you want to know

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dat %>% 
  mutate(y = case_when(y >= dmy("01/06/2020") | y < dmy("01/01/1900") ~ NA_Date_, TRUE ~ y))
#       x      y         
#     <int> <date>    
# 1     1 NA        
# 2     2 1989-10-29
# 3     3 2000-03-16
# 4     4 NA        
# 5     5 NA
```